# Java Basic Login Feature

Tags: java, authentication

I'm trying to implement a login feature in this program. I finally figured it out how to do a basic one, but sadly I do not know how to end it, like for example if the user had finally reached the limit of 3 it should end, but mine still continues and I don't know where and what code I should put in order for it to end than continuing to the main program.

import java.io.*;

public class Password{

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    String name, un, pw;
    String Username = "passwordtest";
    String Password = "test123";
    int stud;
    double math, science, english, filipino, social, ave, sum, fingrade;

    BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for(int trial=1; trial<=3; trial++){
    System.out.print("Username: ");
    un = inpt.readLine();

    System.out.print("Password: ");
    pw = inpt.readLine();

    System.out.println("");

    if (un.equals(Username) && pw.equals(Password)){
        System.out.println("You have successfully logged in!");
        trial=trial+2;
        continue;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, Incorrect Username/Password");
        System.out.println("Please Try Again");
        System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Welcome to ITMinions' Grading System!");
    System.out.println("How many students' grades would you like to record?");
    System.out.print("Answer: ");
    stud=Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

    System.out.println("");

for (int ctr=1; ctr<=stud; ctr++){
    System.out.print("Name of the student: ");
    name = inpt.readLine();

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Input the following grades");

    System.out.print("Math: ");
    math = Double.parseDouble(inpt.readLine());

    if(math<65 || math>100){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again.");
        System.out.println("");
        ctr=ctr-1;
        continue;
    }

    System.out.print("Science: ");
    science = Double.parseDouble(inpt.readLine());

    if(science<65 || science>100){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again.");
        System.out.println("");
        ctr=ctr-1;
        continue;
    }

    System.out.print("English: ");
    english = Double.parseDouble(inpt.readLine());

    if(english<65 || english>100){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again.");
        System.out.println("");
        ctr=ctr-1;
        continue;
    }

    System.out.print("Filipino: ");
    filipino = Double.parseDouble(inpt.readLine());

    if(filipino<65 || filipino>100){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again.");
        System.out.println("");
        ctr=ctr-1;
        continue;
    }

    System.out.print("History: ");
    social = Double.parseDouble(inpt.readLine());

    if(social<65 || social>100){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again.");
        System.out.println("");
        ctr=ctr-1;
        continue;
    }

    sum=math+science+english+filipino+social;
    ave=sum/5;

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The average of " + name + " is: " + ave);
    System.out.println("");

 }

}
```

}

Please help! And yes this is related to school work :)
Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate all the answers thanks guise! I finally made it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the part of the loop that handles succesfull login as follows:

```
    if (un.equals(Username) && pw.equals(Password)){
        System.out.println("You have successfully logged in!");
        break;
    }
```

Notice using the break keyword to break out of the loop.

You can use `System.exit(0);` to exit when the user has used all login attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You must use another variable for example: boolean isLoggedIn, and set that if successfully logged in, and then break instead of continue as below:

```
if (un.equals(Username) && pw.equals(Password)){
    System.out.println("You have successfully logged in!");
    isLoggedIn = true;
    break;
}else{
    System.out.println("Sorry, Incorrect Username/Password");
    System.out.println("Please Try Again");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Then outside the for loop, check if(isLoggedIn) and do actions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your fi statement

```
if (un.equals(Username) && pw.equals(Password)){
        System.out.println("You have successfully logged in!");
        break;;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, Incorrect Username/Password");
        System.out.println("Please Try Again");
        System.out.println("");
        }
    }


if(trail==4)
{
   //Write your locking logic here
}
```

its not good practice to hard code things in your code. Try to use property file for simplicity or if you have time use jdbc

To avoid Null pointer exception use

```
Username.equals(un)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you follow proper Java coding standards like camel-case for variable naming, and all upper case for constants. Since username and password are hardcoded, they are infact constants. So, change

```
String Username = "passwordtest";
String Password = "test123";
```

to

```
final String USERNAME = "passwordtest";
final String PASSWORD = "test123";
```

It would also be better if you could load these constants from a properties file, because when passwords change, you need not modify your code, just edit properties file.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the previous answers:

```
booelan isLoggedIn = false;
for ( int trials = 3; trials > 0; trials-- )
{
  <ask uname, password> // Java convention: don't capitalise variable names
  if ( isLoggedIn = <uname/password are OK> {
    System.out.println ( "Success" );
    break;
  }

  System.out.printf ( "Bad uname/pass, %d attempts remaining\n", trials );
}

if ( !isLoggedIn ) {
  System.out.println ( "User couldn't give valid credentials, quitting after three attempts, due to security reasons" );
  Thread.sleep ( 3000 ) // try to fight brute-force attackers 
  System.exit ( 1 ); // Not zero, it's not a regular end 
}

// Go ahead with your application
```